# Annotate using an extra field from a ManyToMany model in Django

Tags: python, django, model, many-to-many

Straight to the point: 
**models:**

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)        

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    shops = models.ManyToManyField(Shop, through='ProductShop', related_name='products')

class ProductShop(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
```

Now I'd like to get a list of Products ordered by the lowest price available in all the Shops that sell this Product. I've always used `annotate` for such queries, but here I can't think of any solution. Here's roughly what I'd like to get:

```
products = Product.objects.annotate(price=SOMETHING_TO_GET_THE_LOWEST_PRICE_PER_PRODUCT).order_by('price')
```

Is there any nice solution for that? I know about `extra`, but wouldn't like to write plain SQL. I did my best to find an answer, but couldn't google my specific problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last solved it with a slight workaround:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    shops = models.ManyToManyField(Shop, through='ProductShop', related_name='products')
    def lowest_possible_price(self):
        shops = self.shops.all()
        if not shops:
            return "N/A"
        return reduce(lambda x, y: min(x, ProductShop.objects.get(shop__pk=y.id, product__pk=self.id).price), 
                shops, ProductShop.objects.get(shop__pk=shops[0].id, product__pk=self.id).price)
```

```
products = sorted(Product.objects.all(),
        key = lambda product : product.lowest_possible_price())
```

Still bothers me if there'a one-line solution with no helper function (`lowest_possible_price` here)

Answer (score 1):

You mean:

```
products = ProductShop.objects.filter(
   shop__in=Shop.objects.filter()).annotate(Min(price)).order_by('price')

{% for ps in productshop %}
    Shop: {{ ps.product.shop }}
    Product: {{ ps.product }}
    Minimum Price: {{ ps.price }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. First of all, it would return ProductShops, not Products, right? Secondly, what good is annotate if you don't assign its value to anything? I just can't comprehend how it would work and from my tests in CLI it doesn't.

Comment: it would return product. remember productshop has the foreignkey for product so you can access it by {{shop.product.name}}

Comment: Right now, after correcting the annotation to Min('price') it returns the ProductShop objects, sorted according to the price. I can't see how to make it a list of shops though, I suppose it would need some "distinct" or something. But in a normal for loop it should be quite easy to turn those ProductShops into Shops. Still, I like my workaround better. Anyway, thanks for the contribution! :)

Comment: well, it is easy remember productshop have a foreignkey for product so you can simply `{% for ps in productshop %}{{ps.product.shop}}{% endfor %}`, that's it

Comment: It won't work, but I see what you're thinking about. Firstly, Product doesn't have a field named 'shop' (your query wouldn't work). Secondly, I wrote "I'd like to get a list of Products", so here `{{ps.product}}` would do. But, as I said, it could give me the same product multiple times. Assuming that I have one Product `p1` selled by two Shops `s1` and `s2`. I would have two ProductShop objects (`ps1` and `ps2`) and both of them would yield the same `p1` Product in `ps1.product` and `ps2.product`

Comment: sorry it `shops`, `{{ps.product.shops}}`

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that you edited your answer. Yes, the query for products seems fine, but it still would need to filter out duplicates. See the example in my previous comment. But your "Minimum Price" is just the price of the specific Product in the specific Shop, it's not the minimum price. ProductShop objects have reference only to one shop and one product, and the `price` field is the price of the product in the shop.

Comment: we need to use distinct for that, I forgot it has duplicate items

Comment: I agree, with distinct it should work. Still, it's more natural for me to pass a shop list to the template and then iterate over shops, than to pass ProductShop objects, especially when I have this helper function to get the minimum price. Without it would certainly be better to pass ProductShops, as it carries the price with it too. And obviously, I want to render the price in the template, too.